# サブウィンド、が、一つしか開かない（　文字変数が、　評価されない、）

Tags: javascript

```
subWin = new Array(0,10);

var i=0;

for (i; i<4; i++) {
    alert("イン　ループ、OP windo　　!="+ i);
    subWin[i] = window.open("tmp.txt",'"sample"+i ', "newwindow" );
    alert("Get>="+ subWin[i].name+ "==" + " XX" + i );
};
```

この二回目の、アラートで、　二番目の、引数が、＞"sample"+i＜　＜このように表示されます。 シングルクォートを消しても、おなじです。
　動作は、　sanpl1,,sampl2,,,,と、　名前が変わる、ように書きたいのです。

なにか、書き方はありますか？　　どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: すいません。質問を考えてるうちに、答えがうかんで、試したら、できました。　window.open( 　の、第二引数は、そのまま、評価されない。　なんといったらいいのか、 var　name="sampe" ; 定義して，name=name+i ; で、文字列　sampl0,,sampl1,,,  画、つくれて、しかも、アレイ「ｉ」に、あとから代入すると、フォーカスがうつらず、全部の別窓がひらきました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は放置せず、[ご自身で回答を書き、承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)してください。

Answer (score 1):

シングルクォート、ダブルクォートで囲った文字列リテラルはバックスラッシュによるエスケープの解釈以外何もしません。変数を書くことはできません。ですので、文字列リテラル`'"sample"+i '`の値は`"sample"+i`です。

この場合、単に外側のシングルクォートを外せば期待どおりになるはずです。`window.open("tmp.txt", "sample" + i, ...`

また、テンプレート文字列を使うこともできます。この場合は文字列の中で変数を使うことができます。バッククォートで文字列を囲み、評価したい式を `${〜}` で囲みます。

`` window.open("tmp.txt", `sample${i}`, ... ``